# Calling method / attribute from py file within kv file fails

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to call a method `check_login()` in my `kv` file, but it is not recognized, yielding this error when I press the first button in my `kv` file:

```
AttributeError: 'LoginWindow' object has no attribute 'check_login'
```

Here is my code:

**loginpageGUI.py**

```
# importing library
import kivy

# version
kivy.require('1.11.1')

# importing functionality
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# defining screens
class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass
class PreferencesWindow(Screen):
    pass
class HomeWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

# background
Window.clearcolor = (0.67, 0.83, 0.88, 1)

# creating layout class
class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    # defining processing method of the login button
    def check_login(self):

        """
        Processing, will fix later
        """

        print("Login succesful!")

        # reset the textinputs to empty strings once pressed and processed
        self.username.text = ''
        self.password.text = ''

        # navigate to home screen
        app.root.current = "home"
        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

# linking .py with .kv
kv = Builder.load_file('gui.kv')

# creating application class that returns variable kv
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return (kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**gui.kv**

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    HomeWindow:
    PreferencesWindow:

<Button>:
    font_size: 27
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
    background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1
<Label>:
    font_size: 18
    size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
    color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
<TextInput>:
    font_size: 14
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.05

<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"

    MyFloatLayout:
        username: username
        password: password

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.43, 'center_x': 0.5}
            id: to_home
            text: "Login"
            on_press: root.check_login()
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.57, 'center_x': 0.35}
            text: "Username"
        TextInput:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.57, 'center_x': 0.6}
            id: username
            multiline: False

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.5, 'center_x': 0.35}
            text: "Password"
        TextInput:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.5, 'center_x': 0.6}
            id: password
            multiline: False

<HomeWindow>:
    name: "home"

    MyFloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Log out"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.57}

        Button:
            text: "Preferences"
            id: to_preferences
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "preferences"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.43}

<PreferencesWindow>
    name: "preferences"

    Button:
        text: "Home"
        id: to_home
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "home"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.43}

    Label:
        text: "To be further processed"
```

So somehow, the method `login_check()` in class `MyFloatLayout` is not recognized when executing, which makes the program fail. I have looked across SO but haven't found similar problems so far. Some help would be great.

EDIT: I just realized that as of now, the `root` is `LoginWindow`, as this is the root of the button we're talking about here. I'd actually like to call the child of that root, `MyFloatLayout`. How would I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining an id for `MyFloatLayout` in kv file and access it's function by the id. The updated gui.kv file is below:

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    HomeWindow:
    PreferencesWindow:

<Button>:
    font_size: 27
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
    background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1
<Label>:
    font_size: 18
    size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
    color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
<TextInput>:
    font_size: 14
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.05

<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"

    MyFloatLayout:
        id: myfloat
        username: username
        password: password

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.43, 'center_x': 0.5}
            id: to_home
            text: "Login"
            on_press: myfloat.check_login()
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.57, 'center_x': 0.35}
            text: "Username"
        TextInput:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.57, 'center_x': 0.6}
            id: username
            multiline: False

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.5, 'center_x': 0.35}
            text: "Password"
        TextInput:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.5, 'center_x': 0.6}
            id: password
            multiline: False

<HomeWindow>:
    name: "home"

    MyFloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Log out"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.57}

        Button:
            text: "Preferences"
            id: to_preferences
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "preferences"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.43}

<PreferencesWindow>
    name: "preferences"

    Button:
        text: "Home"
        id: to_home
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "home"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.43}

    Label:
        text: "To be further processed"
```

But there are few issues in you loginpageGUI.py file as well. You need define the `app` in `__name__` block and then you can use `app`. Also in `check_login` function need to change `root.manager.transition.direction` to `app.root.transition.direction`. The updated loginpageGUI.py is below:

```
# importing library
import kivy

# version
kivy.require('1.11.1')

# importing functionality
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# defining screens
class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass
class PreferencesWindow(Screen):
    pass
class HomeWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

# background
Window.clearcolor = (0.67, 0.83, 0.88, 1)

# creating layout class
class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    # defining processing method of the login button
    def check_login(self):

        """
        Processing, will fix later
        """

        print("Login succesful!")

        # reset the textinputs to empty strings once pressed and processed
        self.username.text = ''
        self.password.text = ''

        # navigate to home screen
        app.root.current = "home"
        app.root.transition.direction = "right"

# linking .py with .kv
kv = Builder.load_file('gui.kv')

# creating application class that returns variable kv
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return (kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```